# run an IntentService at most once

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have an `IntentService` and I want for the `startCommand` to be called only if it's not already running.

The reason for this is this service is processing all existing rows in database. It can be called to start several times but if it's already running it shouldn't be started again. And similar to `IntentService` after there are no rows to be processed, it should close itself.

Is this achievable? Maybe with `PendingIntent` and `FLAG_NO_CREATE` ?

I could create this with a `Service` and a separate thread instead of a `IntentService` but `IntentService` already has the thread implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe with PendingIntent and FLAG_NO_CREATE ?

That flag refers to creating the `PendingIntent`, not the service.

> Is this achievable?

Off the cuff:

Step #1: In your service, add an `AtomicBoolean` field (here called `isRunning`), initially set to `false`.

Step #2: Override `onStartCommand()`. If `isRunning` is `false`, set it to `true` and chain to `super.onStartCommand()` to inherit normal `IntentService` behavior. If `isRunning` is `true`, do not chain to `super.onStartCommand()`.

Step #3: In `onHandleIntent()`, wrap all your work in a `try`/`finally` block, where you set `isRunning` to `false` in `finally`.

Net: a `startService()` invocation will only go through normal `IntentService` processing if `onHandleIntent()` is not already running.

Comment: Thanks! Ohhhh nice! Trick is to selectively call base class `IntentService` implementation...

Comment: So I don't need an `PendingIntent` I just need to call `startService(intent)` ?

Comment: @DonBox: If you want to start a service yourself, call `startService()`. You use a `PendingIntent` when you want *something else* to start your service (e.g., `AlarmManager`, a `Notification`).